# Convergence of the series $\sum a_n$ when $\sqrt[n]{a_n}\leq 1-\frac{1}{n^\alpha}$ for $0<\alpha<1$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Examine the convergence of the series $\sum a_n$, where: 
>   $$\sqrt[n]{a_n}\leq 1-\frac{1}{n^\alpha}$$
>   for all $n$ ($0<\alpha<1$).

*Attempt.* Since $$\limsup \sqrt[n]{a_n}\leq \limsup\left(1-\frac{1}{n^\alpha}\right)=1$$
we can not use the root test. Comparison test also doesn't work, since $\sum(1-n^{-\alpha})$ diverges to $+\infty$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: What happens when $a_n = 0$? And what when $a_n = (1-\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}})^n$? Does the inequality tell us anything about convergence of the series?

Comment: Ιn the first case we have convergence and in the second i know that $(1-n^{-a})^n\to 0$. (i am not sure about the series)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint：$$\left(1-\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}\right)^n=e^{n\log \left(1-\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}\right)};$$
and $$\log \left(1-\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}\right)<\frac{-1}{n^{\alpha}}.$$
So when $n$ large enough
$$n\log \left(1-\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}\right)<-n^{1-\alpha}.$$
Thus $$0<\left(1-\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}\right)^n<e^{-n^{1-\alpha}}.$$
Combining the convergent of series $\sum e^{-n^{1-\alpha}}$ for $0<\alpha<1$, we know $\sum \left(1-\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}\right)^n$ is convergent by Comparison test.
Also Comparison test implies $\sum a_n$ is convergent.

Comment: Very nice. One remark: why do you need $\ln(1+x)>\frac{x}{x+1}$, since $\ln (1+x)<x$ for $x>-1$ is enough? Also, at the last line you meant $e^{-2n^{1-a}}$ and  $e^{-n^{1-a}}.$

Comment: Yes,  the right inequality is enough. @ Nikolaos Skout